# How to sort an array based on a predefined element order?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would like to sort the elements of an array based on a custom array that defines the element order. For example, assume the following array:

```
let arr = ["second", "first", "second", "fourth", "third", "second"]
```

I tried to create an Array extension to be able to sort this array by:

```
let sortedArr = arr.sortBy(orderArray: ["first","second","third","fourth"])
// desired output: ["first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "fourth":
```

However, the extension does not work correctly:

```
extension Array {
    public func sortBy<T: Comparable>(orderArray: [T]) -> [T]? {
        guard self.count > 0,
            self.first! as? T != nil else {
                return nil
        }

        let indices = self.map {orderArray.index(of: $0 as! T)! }

        return self.sorted { indices[$0] > indices[$1] } // This doesn’t work
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with your code is that `self.sorted` expects a 
closure comparing array *elements,* not indices.

Here is a possible solution which also avoids unnecessary
type casts and unwrappings (explanations inline):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    public func sortBy(orderArray: [Element]) -> [Element]? {

        // Index of each element in `orderArray`:
        let targetIndices = self.flatMap { orderArray.index(of: $0) }
        // Verify that each array element occurs in `orderArray`:
        guard targetIndices.count == self.count else {
            return nil
        }
        // Sort array indices according to their index in `orderArray`:
        let sortedIndices = self.indices.sorted { targetIndices[$0] < targetIndices[$1] }
        // Rearrange elements accordingly:
        return sortedIndices.map { self[$0] }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let arr = ["second", "first", "second", "fourth", "third", "second"]

if let sortedArr = arr.sortBy(orderArray: ["first","second","third","fourth"]) {
    print(sortedArr)
    // ["first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "fourth"]
}
```

---

To move array elements which are not contained in `orderArray`
to the end of the sorted result (but preserve their relative order), modify the code slightly to

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    public func sortBy(orderArray: [Element]) -> [Element] {

        // Index of each element in `orderArray`:
        let targetIndices = self.enumerated().map {
            orderArray.index(of: $1) ?? orderArray.count + $0
        }
        // Sort array indices according to their index in `orderArray`:
        let sortedIndices = self.indices.sorted { targetIndices[$0] < targetIndices[$1] }
        // Rearrange elements accordingly:
        return sortedIndices.map { self[$0] }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let arr = ["x", "second", "first", "y", "second", "fourth", "third", "second", "z"]
let sortedArr = arr.sortBy(orderArray: ["first","second","third","fourth"])
print(sortedArr)
// ["first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "fourth", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Comment: That's a nice and neat solution! Especially, the second last step was the one I couldn’t come up with.

Answer (score 2):

#### Another alternative: emanate from the `orderArray` to construct a sorted array

Another alternative (the "other way around" as compared to [@MartinR:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40015717/4573247)) is to emanate from `orderArray` and simply construct the "sorted" array based on the number of occurences of elements in the `orderArray` in the array to be sorted.

---

***Sub-alternative #1: allow an `orderArray` which is not comprehensive w.r.t. the elements to be sorted***

In the example implementation of this alternative below, elements in the array to be sorted that are not present in the `orderArray` have been left in same relative order as in the original array, but at the end of the part of the array that *does* get sorted (i.e., after any elements that *are* included in `orderArray`). Another alternative could be `nil` return in case the `orderArray` does not fully cover all elements in the array to be sorted.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    /* help method */
    private func countInstances(of element: Element) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == element ? 1 : 0) }
    }

    /* sort by ordered array method */
    func sortBy(orderArray: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        // construct sorted array based on elements in orderArray
        return orderArray
            .reduce([]) { $0 + Array(repeating: $1, count: countInstances(of: $1)) } + 
            filter { !orderArray.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let arr1 = ["second", "first", "unsortable", "second", 
           "anotherUnsortable", "fourth", "third", "second"]
let arr2 = ["foo", "first", "bar"]
let orderArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

print(arr1.sortBy(orderArray: orderArray)) 
    // ["first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "fourth", "unsortable", "anotherUnsortable"]

print(arr2.sortBy(orderArray: orderArray)) 
    // ["first", "foo", "bar"]
```

---

***Sub-alternative #2: for a non-comprehensive `orderArray`, return `nil`***

In case you'd rather return `nil` if `orderArray` is not comprehensive w.r.t. the members of the array to be sorted, yuou can modify the `sortBy` method above accordingly:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    private func countInstances(of element: Element) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == element ? 1 : 0) }
    }

    func sortBy(orderArray: [Element]) -> [Element]? {
        guard reduce(true, { $0 && orderArray.contains($1) }) else { return nil }
        return orderArray
            .reduce([]) { $0 + Array(repeating: $1, count: countInstances(of: $1)) }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let arr1 = ["second", "first", "second", 
            "fourth", "third", "second"]
let arr2 = ["foo", "baz", "bar"]
let orderArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

print(arr1.sortBy(orderArray: orderArray)) 
    // Optional(["first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "fourth"])

print(arr2.sortBy(orderArray: orderArray)) 
    // nil
```

Comment: This is a great alternative! Especially useful in case `orderArray` does not contain all items. Also helpful to see how reduce can be applied such useful. Since the other answer was exactly what I asked for, and I cannot accept two answers, this answer should definitely be upvoted.

Comment: @Taco happy to help! I also believe the other answer should be accepted, as I believe it should have better performance than this one (performance generally not being an issue, but it's naturally important for users applying sortings such as this one to huge arrays).

Comment: @Taco included also the `nil`-returning (for non-comprehensive `orderArray`) version for completeness.